# Laravel how to return the value NULL when hasMany relationship is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In my `laravel`-application I want to return the value `null` when my HasMany-model returns an empty array! How can I achieve that?

I tried to do this:

```
public function something(){
  $collection = $this->hasMany('App\Models\SomeModel');
  return $collection ? $collection : null
}
```

but that still returns

```
{
   something: []
}
```

but I want this to be displayed:

```
{
   something: null
}
```

so, can someone help me out?

Comment: `hasMany` returns a relation object, not a result set ... and use some type of transformer or api resource to make the output how you want it to be for this model

Comment: use like this `return $collection ? $collection : 'null'`

Comment: @A.ANoman its not a collection its a relation type object (not a result) and objects evaluate to `true` ... so what you have there is the same as `return $this->hasMany(...);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use function  `count()` like this:

```
return count($collection) > 0 ? $collection : null;
```